# Hibernate won't insert into database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, insert

Now I have a really strange problem which I'm unable to understand.

I've got hibernate properly configured. I can load data from my mysql database without any problems. But I'm not able to insert data. Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookmaker</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>

<mapping class="de.wettprofi.objects.Bookmaker"/>
<mapping class="de.wettprofi.objects.Match"/>
<mapping class="de.wettprofi.objects.LogEntry"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

It's about the class LogEntry. Here is some code that should persit the object into the database:

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String json = reader.readLine();

        try {
            LogEntry log_entry = null;

            if (json != null && !json.isEmpty()) {
                log_entry = new LogEntry();

                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json_dict = (JSONObject) parser.parse( json );

                //initalize proper LogEntry object
            } 
            if( log_entry != null ) {
                Session session = get_hibernate_session();
                System.out.println("Logging of LogEntry into the database\n" + log_entry.toString() );
                session.save( log_entry );
                session.flush();
                System.out.println("Logging DONE");
            }

        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public Session get_hibernate_session()
    {
        //Opening a hibernate session
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            Configuration hibConfiguration = new Configuration().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").configure();       
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = hibConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sessionFactory.withOptions().openSession();
    }
```

And this is what the LogEntry class object looks like (getters and setters omitted):

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "LogEntries" )
public class LogEntry {

    public static int MESSAGE = 1;
    public static int BOOKMAKER = 2;
    public static int CLICKLOG = 3;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column( name = "lid" )
    public int lid;

    @Column( name = "id" )
    public String id;

    @Column( name = "date" )
    public Date date;

    @Column( name = "type" )
    public int type;

    @Column( name = "message" )
    public String message;

    @Column( name = "bookmaker" )
    public String bookmaker;

    @Column( name = "match_id" )
    public int match_id;

    @Column( name = "result" )
    public String result;


    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("      lid = " + lid  + "\n");
        sb.append("       id = " + id  + "\n");
        sb.append("     date = " + date.toString()  + "\n");
        sb.append("     type = " + type  + "\n");
        sb.append("  message = " + message  + "\n");
        sb.append("bookmaker = " + bookmaker  + "\n");
        sb.append(" match_id = " + match_id  + "\n");
        sb.append("   result = " + result  + "\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

So, when I now run my tomcat instance and have a look on what did happen I get the following output:

```
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 24, 2013 9:55:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Apr 24, 2013 9:55:18 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Logging of LogEntry into the database
      lid = 0
       id = 50569803719166097161
     date = Mon Apr 22 21:01:53 CEST 2013
     type = 1
  message = MainVC
bookmaker = null
 match_id = 0
   result = null

Hibernate: insert into LogEntries (bookmaker, date, id, match_id, message, result, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Logging DONE
```

However after this having a look into my database reveals that nothing has been written to the table.

This is my table schema:

```
mysql> describe LogEntries;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bookmaker | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| match_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| message   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| result    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Has anybody got an idea what might cause this trouble. I'm clueless :(

Comment: just pointing it out `get_hibernate_session()` doesn't follow Java Standard of naming functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity class should have getter and setter for the property.

As well after you are getting session, you need to begin your transaction.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     sess.save(entityObjectToBeinserted);
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Comment: I wrote this comment to early...One moment I need to correct something in my code...

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Another question: Do I have to close the session object after I inserted an object? I mean, I thought the connection to the database would then be closed such that next time the whole process of openning a connection to the database has to be repeated.

Comment: As you are using standalone hibernate, its better to close the session once you are done with the things, latter you can go ahead to open the session from pool. as its a bad idea to keep hold of external resource connection such as data base for long time with out any need..

Answer (score 0):

You need to [declare get/set pairs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html) for every property per the Hibernate documentation. These methods can be public, protected or private, but they must be present.